# Extension of a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

[Extensions of measurable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/76568)
Let $(X,F)$ be a measurable space. $U \subset X$, which is not necessarily measurable. $f$ is a real-valued measurable function defined on $(U,F\cap U)$, then we can extend $f$ to a measurable function on $X$.
The answer in the link above makes me confused, I don’t know because $U$ must be measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever $U$ is measurable or not, we can give such an extension below.

Without loss of generality we can assume $f\geq 0$, since we can decompose $f=f^+-f^-$. Thus, choose a sequence of simple functions $s_n=\sum_{1}^{n}a_j\chi_{A_j}\geq 0$ on $U$, where the $A_j\in \mathcal{F}\cup U$ (I changed the symbol here a little to avoid misunderstanding) and need *not* be pairwise disjoint, such that
\begin{equation}
    s_n\uparrow f \quad \text{on } U\quad  \text{ as } n\to\infty.
\end{equation}
(Note $s_n$ can be written in this form because if you get $s_1\leq s_2\leq\cdots \leq f$, we have $s_n=s_{n-1}+(s_n-s_{n-1})$.)
Since $A_j=F_j\cup U$ where $F_j\in \mathcal{F}$, we can define
\begin{equation}
g_n=\sum_{1}^{n}a_j\chi_{F_j},
\end{equation}
and it is **increasing**!
Let $n\to \infty$; the limit $g$ exists (it can be infinity), $g|_U=f$ and are measurable.
Furthermore, if we hope $g$ is still real-valued, we can change the value on  $g^{-1}(+\infty)$ to zero.

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is not measurable, the linked answer breaks down at two points (I will use the notation in the answer):

1. First, $\mathcal{N}=\{A\cap U\mid A\in\mathcal{M}\}$ may not necessarily be contained in $\mathcal{M}$. (This *would* be the case if $U$ is measurable since $\mathcal{M}$ is closed under intersections.) Therefore, if $S \subseteq \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ doesn't contain zero, then $F^{-1}(S) = f^{-1}(S)$. Although $f^{-1}(S)$ belomgs to $\mathcal{N}$, it may not belong to $\mathcal{M}$.
2. Second, if $S \subseteq \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ contains zero, then $F^{-1}(S) = f^{-1}(S) \cup U^{c}$. But $U^{c} \notin \mathcal{M}$ and once again, we do not if $f^{-1}(S) \in \mathcal{M}$.

Hence we cannot conclude that the constructed extension $F$ is measurable.

Comment: Of course F is not necessarily measurable, so I need a better extension. By the way, maybe we can construct a series of measurable functions and let them convergence to the extension I need.